# Upgrading Spring Boot to 2.5.9 and getting FileNotFoundException: class path ...../boot/actuate/health/HealthAggregator.class] cannot be opened

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I am getting a FileNotFoundException during Spring Boot initiation for org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/HealthAggregator.class. This seem related to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/19860 but that was back in 2.2.

I have tried different versions of Spring Boot, 2.5.9 etc, different versions of Spring Cloud, etc.

Any thoughts on how I can resolved this?

Key parts of my POM

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
..
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
..
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
..
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client-config</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

The error:
is 2022-01-25 20:16:20 WARN  o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.xxxxx.vms.yyyyy]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/HealthAggregator.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist 2022-01-25 20:16:20 ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed

Comment: Why do you have a pom import of `spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client-config`?

Comment: HealthAggregator hasn't been a part of boot since 2.3 so something in your project is referencing an old version of boot. I created a minimal project with boot 2.6 and spring cloud 2021.0 and the starter listed above and was unable to recreate  the error. What does `mvn dependency:tree` say?

Comment: To pick up a configmap for applications.properties. But I worry my problem has to do with spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client-config, so listing here to be transparent.